# Increase every font size across the site proportionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, font-face

I've just changed a site's font to a non-web font. Problem is, the font is really thin and hard to read. So I've to do a quick fix like `* { font-size:125% }` and of course this did not work.

Can this be achieved through pure CSS? Or perhaps there's a clean Javascript/jQuery way?

I am using a pre-made theme so re-doing the entire stylesheet in em is not really an option for me as there are 125 instances of font-size defined, looking through the developer toolbar.

Comment: You may want to use `em`

Comment: You may want to reconsider using a custom font-face for your entire site's text:  http://superuser.com/questions/547743/why-dont-websites-immediately-display-their-text-these-days

Comment: "I am using a pre-made theme so re-doing the entire stylesheet in em is not really an option for me." How is modifying the font-face an option, but not the font-size?  It's CSS, not something etched in stone: override it.

Comment: @cimmanon there are 125 instances of font-size found on this theme.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this with pure CSS is if you were using relative font sizes to begin with.

```
body {
    font-size: 125%;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em; /* or 200% */
}
```

If your font sizes are all defined in a fixed unit size (eg. 12px), then you'll have to go through your entire CSS file and modify them all.

Answer (score 0):

may

`body { font-size:125%!important }`

Answer (score 0):

First, be careful with non-standard web fonts as a system without that font will fall back to the second font which will in turn cause unexpected results, namely large font all over the screen.

Second, why would you have to redo the entire site? How many times do you declare a font size? In general, you should only declare a max of about 6 different sizes. (H tags excluded)

Here is a nice blog on the explanation of the usage of em and why it should be your basis of font size http://clagnut.com/blog/348/

If your really keen on doing it with a hack. The above answers should work or maybe even

```
body * {font-size: 125% }
```

so you can avoid the !important.

For future references, please refer to http://help.dottoro.com/lcsdaoxj.php It is by far the best concise usage on all things css, html, and javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
body { font-size: 125%; }
```

OR

```
body { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: the body selector does not get applied to every element.

Answer (score -1):

If the non-web font doesn't have an auxiliary font with a "Bold" at the end, you can't really change its properties (bold, italic) other than font-size. Also, the css from Michael Aguilar using "!important" is not correct, you need to put a space before the "!" 
so,

```
* {font-size: 125% !important;}
```

should work